# WPF Usercontrol Inheritance

Tags: wpf, inheritance, user-controls

I am new to WPF and I am facing a problem here. In one of our application, few dialogs responsible for similar kind of work. All dialogs have OK and APPLY buttons. But in our new UI Design, these will be displayed on a side bar which is a panel(Yet to decide control). I thought of having a Base Usercontrol which will have OK and APPLY button with few methods. And my other dialogs(which are Usercontrols now in new UI) are derived from this Base User Control.

I downloaded few code samples from internet, but problem didn't solve.

If you have any idea/code sample please share.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

WPF (also WinForm to some extent) doesn't play well with inheritance. You could create the UI in C# code and get inheritance working but I don't think designer play well so you'll be stuck in design mode and in Blend.

To work around it you could create piece of functionality that you want to reuse and use [composition instead of inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance), which is considered a better approach anyway.